# Typescript React - JSON API Object ":" expected when indexing

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript

im getting API Data using Axios in Typescript React.

The JSON Data looks like this :[image]

Im trying to index into 1.tokenAmount.uiAmount to get the number value.

I do this `data?[1]["tokenAmount"]["uiAmount"]` but it gives me the error: `':' expected." Anyone can help? Thanks

**Edit 1:**

```
[
  {
    tokenAddress: '4q5UBXJxE91BZKX548qhU8i5QBWvZdXzS3RZwfTgLQda',
    tokenAmount: {
      amount: '266410891120',
      decimals: 6,
      uiAmount: 266410.89112,
      uiAmountString: '266410.89112',
    },
    tokenAccount: '9RBszShvMKzuUYraqEmADc1NqgrmnKYKEPyC5QaHUUiv',
    tokenName: '',
    tokenIcon: '',
    rentEpoch: 263,
    lamports: 2039280,
  },
  {
    tokenAddress: 'HCgybxq5Upy8Mccihrp7EsmwwFqYZtrHrsmsKwtGXLgW',
    tokenAmount: {
      amount: '6882792379617',
      decimals: 6,
      uiAmount: 6882792.379617,
      uiAmountString: '6882792.379617',
    },
    tokenAccount: 'Dn2CabdDsnJpUygmNdpgFbmFA8znDSdFB9jwofCKf9ar',
    tokenName: 'StarLaunch',
    tokenIcon:
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/solana-labs/token-list/main/assets/mainnet/HCgybxq5Upy8Mccihrp7EsmwwFqYZtrHrsmsKwtGXLgW/logo.png',
    rentEpoch: 263,
    lamports: 2039280,
    tokenSymbol: 'STARS',
    priceUsdt: 8.03,
  },
  {
    tokenAddress: 'HkNK7BL5pSUUzc6ns1mHW5JnzbSG4S9u2QdR3cUuyzSa',
    tokenAmount: {
      amount: '67800000',
      decimals: 5,
      uiAmount: 678,
      uiAmountString: '678',
    },
    tokenAccount: 'HjjSymUBxWFBjfBv5V25QnLfeZr17WTJHa17i9YyiYTd',
    tokenName: '',
    tokenIcon: '',
    rentEpoch: 262,
    lamports: 2039280,
  },
];
```

This is what the Raw Data looks like

Comment: share the shape of the original `data`

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> [mcve]

Comment: I've updated the raw json data :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

```
obj.val?.prop
obj.val?.[expr]
obj.arr?.[index]
obj.func?.(args)
```

`data?[1]["tokenAmount"]["uiAmount"]` is not correct. It should be `data?.[1]["tokenAmount"]["uiAmount"]`

The error your getting is down to TypeScript expecting a type since optional keys look like the following:

```
interface Example {
  key?: string;
}
```

Hence the error: `':' expected.`

Comment: Awesome! Mind marking my response as the answer?

Comment: Yep sure! forgot haha